# Issues with sound since pavumeter is installed

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, vlc

I have an issue with VLC, I have no sound playing until I start Pavumeter.
It happens since I've installed Pavumeter.

To purge the package doesn't solve the issue, it's even worse since I have then no sound at all.

It was working fine for a few months, until I installed pavumeter to check my surround. Since then, when I start VLC, I have no sound playing.
It's only when I start pavumeter that the sound is playing on VLC.

I can't understand why it's happening !

I tried running pulseaudio with some debug

```
pulseaudio --log-level=4 --log-time=1 > ~/pulseverbose.log 2>&1
```

It gives me that log when starting

```
(   0.042|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Optimized build: yes
(   0.042|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] main.c: FASTPATH defined, only fast path asserts disabled.
(   0.042|   0.000) I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Machine ID is e671e1e77eb141c892f6f3c2e1ec2a83.
(   0.042|   0.000) I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Session ID is 65.
(   0.042|   0.000) I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using runtime directory /run/user/1000/pulse.
(   0.042|   0.000) I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using state directory /home/dorian/.config/pulse.
(   0.042|   0.000) I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using modules directory /usr/lib/pulse-13.99.1/modules.
(   0.042|   0.000) I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in system mode: no
(   0.042|   0.000) E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
(   0.042|   0.000) E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
```

and then nothing more when starting a video on VLC or when starting pavumeter.

VLC is using the correct sound card, as does PulseAudio.
Nothing change about that when starting pavumeter.

I would love to have some hints about what's going on between VLC and pavumeter.